# What's the Minecraft enchantment Alphabet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to enchant a Diamond Sword, and I was wondering if there was anyway to tell the difference from one enchantment to the other. I was wondering if the Symbols on the enchantment could be translated into English?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The symbols in the enchanting table have no relation to the actual enchant it yields; they are randomized.

You can translate them, however. The symbols are from Commander Keen's Standard Galactic Alphabet:

[image: Standard Galactic Alphabet]

Again, though, the sentences and phrases are meaningless. Your enchants are random (well, sort of, as of Minecraft 1.8). Good luck.

Comment: That's a really nice little Easter Egg. :-D